# Accessing return values from functions in C and C#

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have a doubt regarding the concept of availability of return values from functions in C/C++ and C#. I know that it's not correct to return a pointer to the variables created in the function(local variables). In this case, if I wanted to create an array of values (say int) and return this array from the function how do I do this? And also if I return a local variable directly (not through a pointer to it) when is the memory allocated for this variable reclaimed by the runtime - is it after the value returned is assigned to the receiver of this value?

Another related question is in C#: the variables created in a function using 'new' operator in C# are created on heap. Is it true in the case of local variables created in a function? If the values returned are by reference/address, isn't it violating the rule mentioned above(C++)? What is the way in which this is achieved in C#?

My questions may seem naive, but I am trying to understand the behavior of compilers and runtimes better. It'd be of great help if you could provide me the answers for these questions.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: C++ and C# are **completely** different in this regard.  Which language are you asking about?

Comment: You're going to be much better off if you stop trying to compare C/C++ and C# memory models. They're entirely different and should be treated as completely separate concepts. You're only going to confuse yourself by following this path.

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing to me: in your title you mention C, and C#. In your question you seem to show interest in C++ and C#. In your tags you have C#, C++, and C. These are three different programming languages. Asking a question like this makes it somewhat difficult to answer. Apples and Oranges.

Answer (score 3):

> Blockquote
>   if I wanted to create an array of values (say int) and return this
>   array from the function how do I do this?

The following would do this in C#

```
public int[] Example(int size)
{

     int[] numbers = new int[size]; 
     return numbers;    

}
```

> And also if I return a local variable directly (not through a pointer
>   to it) when is the memory allocated for this variable reclaimed by the
>   runtime - is it after the value returned is assigned to the receiver
>   of this value?

If you are not returning a pointer then you are just returning a copy of the local variable.  The second part of your question makes no sense.

> Another related question is in C#: the variables created in a function
>   using 'new' operator in C# are created on heap. Is it true in the case
>   of local variables created in a function?

Yes, its created on the heap.

> If the values returned are by reference/address, isn't it violating
>   the rule mentioned above(C++)? What is the way in which this is
>   achieved in C#?

You should not be trying to compare C++ to C# so this question should not be answered.  Besides...what is being achieved is also not clear.

> My questions may seem naive, but I am trying to understand the
>   behavior of compilers and runtimes better. It'd be of great help if
>   you could provide me the answers for these questions.

All these questions are address in ANY C++ or C# novice programmer's book.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure what your question is but to return an array of integers you need to allocate memory that cannot be overwritten by your program for it, you then return a pointer to the array not the array itself:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *i; //integer pointer
    i = return_a_two_integer_array(); //i now points to the location in memory of the return value of return_a_two_integer_array();
    free(i); //the memory is no longer allocated and can be overwritten
}

int *return_a_two_integer_array
{
    int *two_integer_array;
    if(!(two_integer_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*2))) //allocate the memory
    {
        return 0x00; //memory allocation failed
    }
    two_integer_array[0] = 1;
    two_integer_array[1] = 2;
    return two_integer_array; //return the pointer 
}
```

This is in C by the way.

Comment: You should point out this is how you return an integer array in C++.  Besides returning a copy of the array would acceptable in my eyes.

Comment: Well this is C and it's not returning an integer array, it's returning a pointer to a memory address where an integer array is located. I don't know any C++. I did however upvote your post because it had more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> if I wanted to create an array of values (say int) and return this array from the function how do I do this?

The difference is the place where the variable is allocated. Local variables are allocated in the stack whereas global variables are allocates on the heap. You can (at pretty much any place in your program) allocate some heap space by hand. This is done my malloc() (or similar) or some higher level function that calls malloc() internally. Such would be the case when you use new to create a new object.

In order to return an array in C you have to use the heap: Allocate some heap space in *some way you like* (malloc() or new) and return a pointer to it (explicit or by returning a object reference)

In C# you would use a generic List or an array which is both constructed using **new**.

If you return a variable directly without using new (e.g. a return type of int) you use the stack. When the function finishes, the value is written to the register representing the variable of the caller.